# Cannot get CSS divisions to match one another, even though they are identical

Tags: html, css

Apologies for my lack of terminology, I'm brand new to CSS. Currently modifying the main CSS for [my webpage](http://lidaanitato.com/art) based off of [HTML5 UP's Multiverse template](https://html5up.net/multiverse).

I'm trying to set up a division for "film," "other media," and "commercial." I've updated the [main.css](https://github.com/anitato/anitato.github.io/blob/master/assets-art/css/main.css) file to account for sections `#main`, `#other-media`, and `#commercial`.

However, the subsequent added sections [(other media & commercial)](http://lidaanitato.com/art#other-media) don't match the first section [(film or #main)](http://lidaanitato.com/art#main). I'm not sure why this is the case since I just copy-and-pasted the code for each division but changed the division ID names, and if I'm supposed to adjust another part of the main.css?

Thank you so much for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `#main` section the images are background-images of the `a` tags, which have background-size `cover`, in the section `#other-media` the images are regular images ( i.e. `img` tags). You should make them all background-images (with the same settings) to get the same result.

Addition after comment:

Your code for the `<article>` elements in the `#main` section are `a` tags with a `background-image` that has `background-size: cover`, plus an `h2` and a `p` element:

```
<article class="thumb">
  <a class="image" style="background-image: url(&quot;images-art/thumbs/07.jpg&quot;); cursor: pointer; outline: 0px none;"><img src="images-art/thumbs/07.jpg" alt="" style="display: none;"></a>
  <h2>...</h2>
  <p>....</p>
</article>
```

And here's the code for an `<article>` in the `#other-media` section: An `img` tag *inside* an `a` tag, plus an `h2` and a `p` element:

```
<article class="thumb">
  <a href="images-art/fulls/03.jpg" class="image">
    <img src="images-art/thumbs/03.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <h2>...</h2>
  <p>....</p>
</article>
```

SO the difference is the handling of the image: Once as a background-image which fills the article element, and once as an `img` tag...

Comment: The code is identical for all the sections, I just replaced `#main` with `#other-media`. So the size is `cover` for all divisions. Or are you suggesting something different?

Comment: No, it's not. Please read what I added to my answer and have another look at your own code.

Comment: Thank you! I had to fix the main.js and main.scss files to do what you suggested (not just the main.css), but it worked!